# How can I separate values from a dimension in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-field

I have a dimension titled "condition ". It has values for conditions excellent, good/excellent, good, fair, poor, poor/very poor, and very poor. I want to create a calculated field to just include the good/excellent and poor/very poor. I have tried a CONTAINS statement and an IF THEN, it creates the field, but it does not present the data the same way the Condition dimension does. I want to use it on a map.  I expected that once the field was in the details shelf on the map and once the filter was shown I would be able to have a single value dropdown that would reflect the value of either good/excellent or poor/very poor on the map. It gives only an all or null option in the filter. The value is also blank on the tooltip.

Comment: It would be much easier to help you if you could provide some small and practical examples of your problem, your expected final results and what was your idea to solve it.